# What is the data type returned by getopt in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, jython

I have following use of `getopt` in my code:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "", ["admit=", "wardName="])
```

Then I run the code from command line in the following matter:

```
Test.py --args --admit=1 --wardName="CCU"
```

When I print the contents of `opts`, I get the following output:

```
[('--admit', '1'), ('--wardName', 'CCU')]
```

The **first question** is what is the data type of this result? It seems to me like a list of tuples. Is that correct?

The **second question** - is there any convenient way to work with such tuple pairs (if these ARE tuples)? For example, how can I now say: *if admit == 1 then do X*?
I thought of converting the tuples to a dictionary, but is that a good practice?

**P.S.** It shouldn't make any difference this is actually Jython and not pure Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front page of the Python docs describes the Python Library docs as "keep this under your pillow".  The page on getopt is at:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html

You get two lists back from getopt: That list of tuples that you mentioned, followed by the list of remaining arguments after all the options have been parsed out.  Try this:

```
import getopt
args = ['-a', '-b', '-cfoo', '-d', 'bar', 'a1', 'a2']
opts, args = getopt.getopt(args, "abc:d")
print ("opts=" + str(opts))
print ("args=" + str(args))
optdic = dict(opts) # convert options to dictionary
print ("optdic['-c'] = " + str(optdic['-c']))
```

### output:

```
opts=[('-a', ''), ('-b', ''), ('-c', 'foo'), ('-d', '')]
args=['bar', 'a1', 'a2']
optdic['-c'] = foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a list of tuplea. You can use `type()` to check.

A dictionary would work fine.

```
D = dict(opts)
print D['--admit']
print D['--wardName']
```

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way to work with the options and values:

```
import getopt, sys

def main():
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "", ["admit=", "wardName="])
        print opts
    except getopt.GetoptError, err:
        # print help information and exit:
        print str(err)
        sys.exit(2)

    admitArg = False
    wardName = ""

    for o, a in opts:
        if o == "--admit":
            admitArg = a
        elif o == "--wardName":
            wardName = a
        else:
            assert False, "unhandled option"

    # do something with the argument values
    if admitArg:
        print "--admit is True"

    if wardName == "Foobar":
        print "wardName is Foobar!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```